# Ubuntu Dual Boot UEFI vs Legacy Boot Issues

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

A little background, I’m trying to install xubuntu on my mom’s laptop HP Envy17 Windows 7.
Initially, I was having issues installing and found a fix where I setup a 200MB EFI partition. I’ve managed to install xubuntu; however, booting is not straight forward.

Upon booting the system, I get the following error:[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkcTS.jpg)

To boot into ubuntu my current  workaround is to enter Startup Menu> Boot Device options>Boot From EFI File >[Enter This directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88fRK.jpg)

EFI>ubuntu>grubx64.efi > boots ubuntu.

2 Issues:

1. This is not straight forward enough for my mom to follow. She is not tech savy at all.
2. I can’t seem to locate how to boot into the windows drive I’ve left on the system.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

[Here is a snapshot of my hd partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImmJS.jpg). I went kind of nuts creating, root, home, and swap and may have made a mistake.

[Also here is a snapshot of my bootorder in my bios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9duKV.jpg) incase this would be helpful too.

Comment: You should install Ubuntu in the same mode as Windows, legacy most likely.  HPs do have some workarounds to UEFI incompatibilities, but a legacy install avoids all those anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying to use the boot-repair utility from an Ubuntu distro (there is a chance it might not work, it will also warn you if the boot partition is too far away from the start of the drive, some older BIOS stuff won't look at the whole drive)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

If this doesn't work and your device is actually UEFI only, rEFInd *might* just work.

Comment: Thanks for this. This solved issue 1: streamlineing the boot up. But still cannot boot the windows partition. I'm thinking I'll need to reinstall using the legacy workflow because my windows was installed via legacy workflow. I'll follow this guide and follow up. [link](https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/how-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-lts-bionic-beaver-on-uefi-and-legacy-bios-system.html)

Comment: Sounds good to me, good luck, Brandon.